# CMD batch escaping environment variable in params

Tags: command-line, batch, environment-variables

I have to write a batch file with a environment variable a param:

```
c:\myapp.exe -f "%APP_HOME%\file.conf"
```

I need to pass exactly the string `%APP_HOME%` as param and not its value. How can I do?

In other words, I don't want to strip the variable in the batch runtime but I would like to let the application use it as parametrized path, if I change this environment variable I don't want to change the variable in the application.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the percent signs with a caret (^)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I need to pass exactly the string "%APP_HOME% as param

1. Replace `%` with `^%`
2. Remove the `"`s

   c:\myapp.exe -f ^%APP_HOME^%\file.conf

test.cmd:

```
@echo %1 %2 %3
```

output:

```
F:\test>test c:\myapp.exe -f ^%APP_HOME^%\file.conf
c:\myapp.exe -f %APP_HOME%\file.conf
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: Ok, but should I remove also the double quotes? How to solve if there is a space in the path?

Comment: @Tobia You have to remove the quotes to stop the expansion. You can put the quotes back inside the batch file if necessary.

Comment: @Tobia Try escaping the space with another caret.  Not sure that will work in Windows, but worth a test.

Comment: @Tobia You could can try using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`.  http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: @paradroid `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` doesn't help.

Comment: @Tobia `echo "%3"` will add the quotes back in the batch file.